# Npm: Declaring a dependency in package.json that a sub-dependency uses

Tags: npm, dependencies

Let's say this is your app's package.json:

```
package.json // (my app)
- foo@2.0
- bar@1.0
    - foo@1.0 // (bar@1.0's package.json)
```

When running the app, which version of "foo" does the "bar@1.0" dependency use?

Thanks!